# Avoid New Page before and after include

Tags: page-breaking, include

I'd like to have some chapters on the same page without page breaks.

Here you are my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
  
    \include{capitoli.tex}

    \include{frontespizio.tex}          

    {
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
        \tableofcontents
    }
    
    \include{chIntroduzione.tex}        
    
    \include{chNozioni.tex}            
    
    \include{chRicerca.tex}
    
    \include{chConclusioni.tex}

    \renewcommand\bibname{Riferimenti}
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Every `\include` is a different chapter. I'd like to have no page breaks between them.
Is there a simple way to do it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: use `\input` instead of `\include`?

Comment: `\include` always issues a new page otherwise one might end up with some interesting timing issues with the generated `.aux` file. However, in the example you provide I assume that each included file are chapters each with its own `\chapter` command, this command already starts a new page so what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I solved using `\input` as @UlrikeFischer said. Then I added `\begingroup` as the first instruction of every file, `\let\clearpage\relax` right after and `\endgroup` as the last instruction of every file

Comment: `\let\clearpage\relax` will break latex and can easily make your document loop forever. Whatever the intention of that, there must be better ways

Comment: in `report` class  every `\chapter` starts a new page so your example document should have _no_ extra empy pages because of `\include`. Please provide an example `that shows the issue.